# Translating Name on Kesubah

Tags: names, ketubah

Does anyone know the meaning/origin of the female name "וועלער," which I found in an old kesubah?

[image]

Comment: is there any chance it's a last name?

Comment: Weller as a last name?

Comment: @rosends that's how google translates it! https://www.google.com/search?q=translate&newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALiCzsaZCS9qqwPnMpP2ORw4H47w9kq1LQ%3A1672323821072&ei=7aKtY5uDBNeM8gKk84SIBA&oq=tra&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQARgAMgQIIxAnMgQIIxAnMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgcIABCxAxBDMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgsIABCABBCxAxCDATIOCC4QgAQQsQMQxwEQ0QM6CgguEMcBENEDEEM6BQgAEIAEOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoKCC4QsQMQgwEQQ0oECEEYAEoECEYYAFAAWPkBYLEIaABwAXgAgAFqiAG0ApIBAzAuM5gBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp

Comment: also translates as "who" if you put a ? https://www.google.com/search?q=translate&newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALiCzsaZCS9qqwPnMpP2ORw4H47w9kq1LQ%3A1672323821072&ei=7aKtY5uDBNeM8gKk84SIBA&oq=tra&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQARgAMgQIIxAnMgQIIxAnMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgcIABCxAxBDMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMgsIABCABBCxAxCDATIOCC4QgAQQsQMQxwEQ0QM6CgguEMcBENEDEEM6BQgAEIAEOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoKCC4QsQMQgwEQQ0oECEEYAEoECEYYAFAAWPkBYLEIaABwAXgAgAFqiAG0ApIBAzAuM5gBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz-serp

Comment: @JoelK The name reads: וועלער בת אהרון.

Comment: It reads "Veler" according to this site: https://www.cs.uky.edu/~raphael/yiddish/harkavy/index.utf8.html - and if you click on the number 148, you get on the top right of that page the definition: zeal, will, inclination. Apparently, it's a Yiddish word.

Comment: On this site, it is said that it is an Russian surname: https://www.jewishgen.org/belarus/lists/Vitaly_Minsk_Revision_List_1811.html

Comment: Although I provided an answer, I do think this question is going to be closed, because it is off-topic for Mi Yodeya.

Answer (score 0):

According to multiple sites, see [here](https://www.cs.uky.edu/%7Eraphael/yiddish/harkavy/index.utf8.html) and [here](https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Kremenets/web-pages/documents/images-from-vr/Surnames-Hebrew-and-Russian-graphics.docx), it is an Russian/Yiddish, Jewish surname.

It appears on [page 338](https://kehilalinks.jewishgen.org/Kremenets/web-pages/documents/images-from-vr/Surnames-Hebrew-and-Russian-graphics.docx) of the document "Surnames Hebrew and Russian Images and their Transliterations, Extracted from the Jewish Vital Records of Kremenets" by Dr. Ronald D. Doctor, Co-Coordinator, Kremenets Shtetl CO-OP/JRI-Poland, Kremenets-District Research Group (6 december 2017).

Apparently it is a Russian Jewish surname famous back in 1811, [a year prior Napoleon invaded Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_invasion_of_Russia). It is a list of the Minsk Jewish meshchane.

Meshchane, [source](https://www.jewishgen.org/Belarus/misc/definitions/index.html#):

> MESCHANIN represents the social status of the family. The reason to
> have this information in the records for Russian authorities wasn’t to
> state the persons origin, but to indicate his social status. People in
> the Russian Empire didn’t have equal civil rights. Therefore it was
> important for it to be registered in documents. A Moscow meshchanin
> had different civil rights than an Ivenets meshchanin. The combination
> of such things as “soslovie” (like meshchanin), religion, gender,
> residence and age produces a picture of the opportunities that the
> person and his/her family had in the Russian Empire.
>
> A Russian register class that united the inhabitants of villages,
> towns and cities where the capital was less than 1,000 rubles -
> generally merchants.